# callback angular js function in socket

Tags: angularjs, callback, socket.io

```
var da="";
var app = angular.module('variantStore', []);
alert("javascript connected");

var socket = io();
$q = 2; //question number

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Enter");
    socket.emit('varq',$q);
    alert("qn:"+$q);
});
socket.on('tan',function(da){
        //alert(da);
        window.v=da;
    app.controller('VariantCardDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){alert("qw"+v);$scope.variant = da;}]);
});
```

app.controller is not working,
seems like i have issues with making a proper callback.

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping socket.io into a service and use it inside controller instead of dynamically creating controller on socket.io event

Comment: I don't know how to create service. Is there any alternative.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this article on angularjs and socket.io from HTML5 Rocks

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/

i think it will give you pretty good idea how to make things work the proper way

Cheers and good luck